# Simple pretty urls with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a one page blog php website.
Content is dynamicaly loaded based on get parameters. I would like to use my htaccess to make pretty urls. I have these urls:

```
website.com/index.php?category=review&page=1
```

And I would like to have this:

```
website.com/category/review/page/1
```

And I also use article as get parameter. So I would like to change this:

```
website.com/index.php?article=12345-name-of-article
```

To this:

```
website.com/article/12345-name-of-article
```

I am totally new to htaccess, so any help would be appreciated.

I tried this rewrite rule: 
`RewriteRule ^article/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ index.php?article=$i [NC,L]`. 
It worked somehow, but php script does not recognize url parameters. So it does not work.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please show some attempts

Comment: I tried this rewrite rule: RewriteRule ^article/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ index.php?article=$i [NC,L]. It worked somehow, but php script does not recognize url parameters. So it does not work.

Comment: [NC,QSA, L] - you ne3ed to add QSA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use QSA - When the replacement URI contains a query string, the default behavior of RewriteRule is to discard the existing query string, and replace it with the newly generated one. Using the [QSA] flag causes the query strings to be combined. :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^article/([\w-]+)(?:\.html|/)?$ index.php?article=$1 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^category/([\w-]+)/page/([\w-]+)(?:\.html|/)?$ index.php?category=$1&page=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Unfortunately no. I am getting 404 Page not found

Comment: What is URL in browser that returns 404 to you? Also are there any more rules in this .htaccess?

Comment: Complete htaccess is: RewriteEngine On 

RewriteRule ^article/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?article=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^category/([\w-]+)/page/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?category=$1&page=$2 [NC,QSA,L]

Comment: And the url is: https://dev.website.com/blog/article/2970-x6-duvodu-proc-si-na-ctenare-koronavirus.html

Comment: Is `blog` a real directory? Where is this .htaccess located?

Comment: yes, blog is a real directory. .htaccess is located inside blog directory